# Recursion inside expression used in property getter

Tags: c#, .net, function, lambda, expression

How to avoid recursion call in property getter? Here is my simple code

```
public class UploadAttribute : Attribute
{
    private Type _resourceType;
    private string _select;
    private string _change;
    private string _remove;

    public Type ResourceType
    {
        get { return _resourceType; }
        set { _resourceType = value; }
    }

    public string Select
    {
        get { return GetResourceText(m => m.Select, "Select..."); }
        set { _select = value; }
    }

    public string Change
    {
        get { return GetResourceText(m => m.Change, "Change..."); }
        set { _change = value; }
    }

    public string Remove
    {
        get { return GetResourceText(m => m.Remove, "Remove"); }
        set { _remove = value; }
    }

    private string GetResourceText(Expression<Func<UploadAttribute, string>> expression, string @default)
    {
        var value = expression.Compile().Invoke(this); // here .net is creating new UploadAttribute instance and use it for expression fnc
        var result = value ?? @default;

        if (_resourceType != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
        {
            ResourceManager rm = new ResourceManager(_resourceType);
            try
            {
                result = rm.GetString(value);
            }
            catch
            {
                // if string wasn't found in resource file than use what user specify; don't by big brother.
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

But if you look at method GetResourceText, there is line where I need to compile and invoke expression to get value for given property. Unfortunately this operation creates new instace of UploadAttribute. In that moment .net goes thru all properties and call getter, if I'm not mistaken, and in getter .net compiles and invokes expression to get value or given property, again, again and again to StackOverlowException.
Can you advice me how to avoid this behavior but with simplicity of this solution?

**Edit:** The porpose of this class is provide caption for buttons - what user sets with ability to use multi language caption from resource manager.
In example above is button Select translated from Resources, for Change button is used default text "Change..." and for Remove button caption "Destroy this @&#!". So if user doesn't specify property value, application use default text, otherwise try to find text in resources and if match is found than use text from resources else use what user set.

```
[Required]
[Upload(ResourceType = typeof(Resource), Select = "UploadSelect", Remove = "Destroy this @&#!")]
public HttpPostedFileBase Logo { get; set; }
```

Comment: It appears that you are setting the attributes property values to two different kinds of values: (1) a resource key that is to be used to retrieve a caption string from the resources, (2) a literal string that is to be used as the caption itself. This is definitely not a clean way to do it, and although I would never choose a brittle design solution like this myself, I guess it could be made to work. I will update my answer according to my new understanding of your purposes.

Comment: To me it is not clear what this code is supposed to do. Maybe you could clarify your intentions, and then you might be able to get an answer that satifies your requirements :)

Comment: @SebastianBusek could you indicate if any of the answers sufficiently addressed your question or alternatively indicate what remaining problems you have. Or, if you found a way to solve the question yourself in a different manner, post it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty dump. It doesn't creates new instances at all; I answered my question in moment when I asked.

`return GetResourceText(m => m.Select, "Select...");` is recursion without end, but `return GetResourceText(m => m._select, "Select...");` isn't, because I'm not calling method GetResourceText again.

I'm sorry boys for silly question.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that what you are trying to achieve is to have some way of initializing these properties if they are not explicitly set. The manner in which you are doing that, will not work.

The `m => m.Remove` type expressions will cause calling the property getter again in infinite recursion until a stack overflow occurs.

You could use a `lazy` construct as illustrated below. It works as follows:

1. If the user does not specify a value for a property, it will return the hard-coded default value when the property getter is invoked.
2. If the user specifies a value for a property, that value it will be used first as a key in an attempt to retrieve a corresponding string value from the resources. If the resource is not found, it is used as the value for the property, provided that it is not empty, otherwise it will fall back on the hard-coded default value.

Note that this dual purpose for an attribute property value leads to a rather brittle design solution. If a resource with key "UploadSelect" is not found, that will become the caption on the button.

```
public class UploadAttribute : Attribute
{
    private static readonly string kSelectDefaultCaption = "Select...";
    private static readonly string kChangeDefaultCaption = "Change...";
    private static readonly string kRemoveDefaultCaption = "Remove...";

    private Type _resourceType;
    private Lazy<string> _select = new Lazy<string>(() => kSelectDefaultCaption);
    private Lazy<string> _change = new Lazy<string>(() => kChangeDefaultCaption);
    private Lazy<string> _remove = new Lazy<string>(() => kRemoveDefaultCaption);

    public Type ResourceType
    {
        get { return _resourceType; }
        set { _resourceType = value; }
    }

    public string Select
    {
        get { return _select.Value; }
        set { _select = new Lazy<string>(() => GetResourceText(value, kSelectDefaultCaption)); }
    }

    public string Change
    {
        get { return _change.Value; }
        set { _change = new Lazy<string>(() => GetResourceText(value, kChangeDefaultCaption)); }
    }

    public string Remove
    {
        get { return _remove.Value; }
        set { _remove = new Lazy<string>(() => GetResourceText(value, kRemoveDefaultCaption)); }
    }

    private string GetResourceText(string key, string @default)
    {
        // initialize to default.
        var result = @default;
        if (_resourceType != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(key))
        {
            // initialize to the value of the key, 
            // that could be a user supplied string literal
            result = key;

            // attempt to retrieve it from the resources.
            ResourceManager rm = new ResourceManager(_resourceType);
            try
            {
                result = rm.GetString(key);
            }
            catch
            {
                // could not retrieve key, using the key value as the result.
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Alex for reply. If I'm understanding well to your code, than user can set property value but he/she isn't able to use localization from resources... But maybe if you replace `set { _select = new Lazy<string>(() => value); }` with `set { _select = new Lazy<string>(() => GetResourceText(value, "Select...")); }` it can work, am I right?

Comment: @SebastianBusek I am not sure if I understand what you mean by that. What the code above does, is to return the value set by the user of the class in case the property value is explicitly set by the user, pull the value from the resources in case it is not set, where it will return the `@default` in case no value with `key` is present in the resources. If this is not the behavior you intended, can you please update your question to specify what it is that you want to achieve?

Comment: Is it your intention that these properties hold the value of the resource key that is to be used to retrieve a corresponding value from the resources?

Answer (score 1):

An slight modification to Alex's answer, if you wish to keep your compile-time safety on using the property names:

```
public class UploadAttribute : Attribute
{
    private Type _resourceType;
    private Lazy<string> _select;
    private Lazy<string> _change;
    private Lazy<string> _remove;

    UploadAttribute()
    {
        _select = new Lazy<string>(() => GetResourceText(m => m.Select, "Select..."));
        _change = new Lazy<string>(() => GetResourceText(m => m.Change, "Change..."));
        _remove = new Lazy<string>(() => GetResourceText(m => m.Remove, "Remove..."));
    }

    public Type ResourceType
    {
        get { return _resourceType; }
        set { _resourceType = value; }
    }

    public string Select
    {
        get { return _select.Value; }
        set { _select = new Lazy<string>(() => value); }
    }

    public string Change
    {
        get { return _change.Value; }
        set { _change = new Lazy<string>(() => value); }
    }

    public string Remove
    {
        get { return _remove.Value; }
        set { _remove = new Lazy<string>(() => value); }
    }
    private string GetResourceText(Expression<Func<UploadAttribute, string>> expression, string @default)
    {
        var result = @default;
        var memberExpression = expression.Body as MemberExpression;
        if (_resourceType != null && memberExpression != null)
        {
            ResourceManager rm = new ResourceManager(_resourceType);
            try
            {
                result = rm.GetString(memberExpression.Member.Name);
            }
            catch
            {
                // if string wasn't found in resource file than use what user specify; don't by big brother.
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```